# NIST DRBG algorithms' optional parameter

Tags: random-number-generator, nist

As I'm going through [NIST-SP-800-90Ar1](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-90a/rev-1/final) spec for DRBG, I found the mention of *security_strength* in all of the 3 specified construct in the document: Hash_DRBG, HMAC_DRBG, CTR_DRBG. However, they're all noted as optional:

> 4. *security_strength*: The security strength for the instantiation. This parameter is optional for **Hash_DRBG**, since it is not used.

and

> 4. *security_strength*: The security strength for the instantiation. This parameter is optional for **HMAC_DRBG**, since it is not used.

and

> {3 no df, 4 with df}. *security_strength*: The security strength for the instantiation. This parameter is optional for **CTR_DRBG**.

And in the disgraced previous version, there wasn't even mention of this parameter.

What is, or what can we infer as, the rationale for its inclusion?

Comment: Maybe to generalize the DRBG interface in case some other non-NIST implementations decide to behave differently on different security strength inputs, e.g. switching between AES-128 and AES-256?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer is that [the 2012 version of SP 800-90A](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-90a.pdf) included a fourth DRBG construction, Dual_EC_DRBG (§10.3.1.2), for which the `security_strength` parameter was required. Since one DRBG flavor required this parameter, to have a common interface, all DRBG flavors had to take this parameter. In Dual_EC_DRBG, `security_strength` is used only for one thing: to select the curve.

> Using the `security_strength` and Table 4 in Section 10.3.1, select the smallest
>   available curve that has a security strength `security_strength`. The values for
>   `seedlen`, `p`, `a`, `b`, `n`, `P`, `Q` are determined by the curve.

Dual_EC_DRBG [was retired after it became public that is was probably backdoored by NSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10417/explaining-weakness-of-dual-ec-drbg-to-wider-audience), but its legacy survives in this minor way.

What escapes me is why Dual_EC_DRBG chooses the curve based on the security strength, whereas Hash_DRBG and HMAC_DRBG are parametrized by a choice of hash algorithm and CTR_DRBG is parametrized by a choice of block cipher.

Comment: It's almost as though the Dual_EC_DRBG parts of the standard were designed by another party who imposed their own conventions on NIST, leaving NIST to figure out how to make it fit into the standard…